# Запуск стороннего Java applet в приложениии вне браузера

Tags: java, httpclient, applet, jetty

Здравствуйте. Существует ли какой-нибудь способ запуска Java applet в приложениии вне браузера?

*Теперь подробнее...* Есть обрудование, которое управляется через web интерфейс. Пройдя авторизацию на странице приветствия, появляется возможность вызвать консоль управления, которая представляет собой Java applet. Соответственно, если закрыть браузер, то и апплет закрывается. С помощью Jetty HttpClient можно имитировать работу браузера, осуществлять запросы GET,POST, пройти авторизацию, получить Cookie, сохранить Content в виде html страницы, пропарсить ее, заменить поля и т.д. Но вот как запустить apllet для меня осталось загадкой. Пробовал запустить с помощью appletviewer типа `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("appletviewer " + appletHtmlFile.getAbsolutePath());`, но не вышло, так как это другой процесс и другая сессия, в которой нет авторизации. Может есть какие-нибудь билиотеки Java или стороннии, позволяющие имитировать работу браузера, включая запуск Java applet. Решения в глобальной сети я не нашел, а копаться в исходниках старых браузеров (они же как-то запускают) мне пока не под силу.

*Для чего это нужно...* У нас в инфраструктуре организации развернут Zabbix, есть оборудование использующее Java applet, оно отрисовано на картах и мониторится. Для быстрого доступа с иконки в карте к консоли управления оборудования с определенными параметрами (можно прописать в описании апплета) это и планируется. Пытаюсь реализовать на Java, потому что занимаюсь ее изучением, а так же по причине наличия Java gateway в Zabbix server. Подробности описывать не буду, так как это не относится к вопросу.

Comment: у вас есть исходный код applet?

Comment: Нет. Это стороннее оборудование, соотведственно веб сервер на самой "железке".

Comment: посмотрите на Java Web Start Applications. applet можно [переделать](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet_migration.html) в Java Web Start Applications.